# Is there a way to override assignmenet operator in JS ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class:

```
    export default class MyClass {
  constructor(data) {
    this.Value = data;
  }
  @observable Value;
}
```

I want to be able to do the following

```
this.myClass = new MyClass();
this.myClass = someData;
```

I want to be able to override an assignement operator in `MyClass` so I can do what I need to do with the someData that is passed into to.

Comment: Have you looked at [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)?

Comment: Elaborate, please? :)

Comment: You cannot overload the assignment operator. You could make `.myClass` a setter, but you cannot define this in `MyClass`

Comment: If you familiar with C# or C++, there is a way to override certain parameters, I want to be able to do the same

Comment: @Bergi I'm pretty sure that you can override assignments for object properties [using proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set).

Comment: @AaditMShah can you show an example ?

Comment: @AaditMShah You can define assignment behaviour for your instance's properties, but you cannot define what happens when your instance is *being* assigned.

Comment: @Pacman JavaScript is not C++ or C#.

Comment: @Bergi, gee what an epiphany I just had, thanks to your comment (eye rolls)

Comment: `this.myClass`  you can make myClass a property with a getter / setter.